# GWT event handlers blocking UI

Tags: gwt

I'm new to GWT.  I creating a MVP based project (as described [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture)) that uses a number of custom events.  There are several widgets (10+) that listen for some global events and perform some action (including writing to the DOM) in the event handlers.

What I'm finding is that the UI blocks and doesn't update until each and every one of the handlers for the one event finishes processing.  This is causing the UI to perform slowly on page load and for any other events that cause the widget to update.

I created a similar project in plain JavaScript/jQuery and this was not an issue with that project.  In fact, the UI was blazing fast.  What am I doing wrong here?  The documentation states that GWT is very performant, so I have to conclude that I'm just doing it wrong.

One example, I have a drop down that selects a date preset (like Yesterday, or Last Week).  When this happens I set the selected preset in the model like so:

```
    public void setDateRange(DatePreset dateRange) {
    this.dateRange = dateRange;
    eventBus.fireEvent(new DateChangedEvent(dateRange));
}
```

Each of the widgets has access to the same eventbus and registers to handler DateChanged events.  Each of the widgets needs to do a fair amount of logic and processing (including making an ajax call) to then update itself with correct data.

```
    @Override
public void onDateChanged(DateChangedEvent event) {
    DatePreset dateRange = event.getDate();
    … additional processing and logic
    … ajax call
}
```

I've determined after some basic profiling that each widget requires about 100-150ms to finish processing (which means there's a UI delay of over one to two seconds).  When I say blocking, I mean the dropdown where I selected the date preset doesn't even close (and I see the spinny wheel) until everything finishes.

What can I do to make this run faster (and without UI blocking)?  I am open to any ideas.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you running in `Production mode` ? `Developer mode` ? Which version of `GWT` are you using? Try a more precisely profiler like `SpeedTracer`. There could be a thousand reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Measuring the speed of the project in developer mode can be a reason for this extreme slowness.

You can check out the real speed of the application if you deploy it to an appserver or if you delete the `&gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997` part from the end of the url in devmode.